# Integrating product of Heaviside step function and Delta functions

Tags: integration, dirac-delta, greens-function, step-function

I want to calculate the following integral:

$$I_1 = \int_{\eta_0}^0d\eta'\int d^3x'~a^4(\eta')~G(x,x')~\frac{\lambda~\delta^3\left(\vec{x}'\right)}{a^3(\eta')}~,$$

where $$G(x,x') =  -\frac{\theta(\eta - \eta')}{2\pi}\left[\frac{\delta\left[(\eta-\eta')^2 - (\vec{x}-\vec{x}')^2\right]}{a(\eta)a(\eta')} + \frac{H^2}{2}\theta(\eta-\eta' - |\vec{x} - \vec{x}'|)\right]$$

If I consider the first term, I can do the following:

$$T_1 = - \frac{1}{2\pi~a(\eta)}\int_{\eta_0}^0d\eta'\theta(\eta - \eta')\int d^3x' ~\delta^3(\vec{x}')\delta\left[(\eta- \eta')^2 - (\vec{x}-\vec{x}')^2\right]~.$$

Now, I can write the one dimensional delta function as $\delta(f(\eta'))$ where

$$f(\eta') = \eta'^2 - 2 \eta~\eta' + \eta^2 - (\vec{x}-\vec{x}')^2.$$ Then, using the property of delta functions $\delta(f(y)) = \sum_i\frac{\delta(y-y_i)}{f'(y_i)}$, I can evaluate this term to be

$$T_1 = -\frac{1}{4\pi~a(\eta)}\int_{\eta_0}^0\theta(\eta - \eta')\left\{\frac{\delta(\eta'-\eta - |\vec{x}|)}{\vec{x} - \vec{x}\cdot \vec{v}} - \frac{\delta(\eta'-\eta + |\vec{x}|)}{\vec{x} + \vec{x}\cdot \vec{v}}\right\}$$

with $\vec{v} = \frac{d\vec{x}}{d\eta'}$. But now, I obtain this product of delta function and the step function which I am not sure how to integrate. The result obtained so far also does not look very similar to what I'm supposed to get which is given in Eqn 19 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.11113.pdf) paper. How do I proceed?